# reindex a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This is embarrassing, I have done this a million times, but for some reason I am not able to `reindex` this `Dataframe`

The `Dataframe df` looks like this:

```
                                          expirations, symbol     
0  [2021-06-04, 2021-06-11, 2021-06-18, 2021-06-2...   AAPL
```

After I reindex it with

```
symbolStr = "AAPL"
df = df.reindex([symbolStr])
```

and print df:

```
print(df)

AAPL         NaN    NaN
```

If instead I say:

```
df = df.set_index(['AAPL'])
KeyError: "None of ['AAPL'] are in the columns"
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `reindex` is used on indexes. AAPL is not in your index, it appears that only `0` is.

Comment: Are you looking for `set_index` instead?

Comment: See original post. I tried set_index, but that also gives an error.

Answer (score 1):

Duh,

```
set_index('symbol')
```

The column name. I saw examples in the actual documentation that shows set index of the column `values`!